# Custom Radio Buttons with This HTML structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radio-button

I would like to customize radio buttons, however, I am limited to acheiving this with either CSS or JavaScript. My html structure is as follows:

```
<label for='radio'>
  <span></span>
  <input type='radio' />
</label>
```

While keeping this HTML structure, what is the best way for me to design custom radio buttons? I can append images with JS. I just can't touch the source HTML. Ideally, I would want the button to be fully green when checked and just have an outline of green if not checked. See snippet for an example

```css
.checked
{
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  border:1px solid green;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color:green;
}
.notChecked
{
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  border:1px solid green;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Checked</p>
<div class="checked"></div>
<p>Not Checked</p>
<div class="notChecked"></div>
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand where you're having trouble. Seems that you have the right approach. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't see any effort you are trying to make that custom radio button. Provide the code which you have tried and failed to achieve and we will able to help you out.

Comment: You can try using CSS before and after pseudo classes for span elements and achieve the style you wish.